How should I go about solving an equation with the same trigonometric function on both sides?
I know of a couple ways to do it using formulas, but it's a bit long winded. Take $\sin{(5x+60°)} =\sin{(2x+30°)}$. Taking inverse sine of both sides gives $5x+60° = 2x+30°+360°n$ and $5x+60° = 180°-(2x+30°)+360°n$ but the latter gives an incorrect answer. Why is this, and how should I go about solving it? Would I have to take careful consideration of any other trig functions like this, including the reciprocal functions?
The first equation gives the solution: $x=-10° + 120°n$ which is correct, and the other equation gives $x=\frac{90°}{7} + \frac{360°}{7}n$. My calculator is saying the answers are $x=\frac{90°}{7} + \frac{720°}{7}n$, $x=\frac{450°}{7} + \frac{720°}{7}n$, and $x=-10° + 120°n$

There is an identity for $\sin A - \sin B$ you could use. I wouldn't say this method is "long-winded"?

"...but the latter gives an incorrect answer...." : please edit your posted question  to show all of your work, in very clear detail.

When you invert trig functions you'll need to restrict yourself to some interval of length $2\pi$ to ensure it's invertible on that region. Once you've found $x$ in that region use periodicity to find the other solutions.

What is your answer in the second case, and what is the correct answer?
